# Upon initial environment create using eb create the ebextensions are not reflected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

Below is the setup of the application which runs a docker container into elasticbeanstalk.

[image]

**step 1:**

created the parent folder say apptest and inside that I have placed the Dockerfile, package.json and small hello world server.js node app.

**step 2:**

inside the parent folder `apptest` ran the command `eb init` which crated a hidden folder `.elasticbeanstalk` with `config.yml` comprising default settings.

**step 3:**

added `.ebextensions` with a config file `01_run.config`, comprising the below configuration to update the instance type.

```
option_settings:
    aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration :
        InstanceType : "m4.xlarge"
```

Note that till now no environment is created yet. And since I have extensions created, should override the defaults with the instance type pointed to `m4.xlarge`.

**step 4:**

Now ran the command `eb create apptest-dev` ( say for example ) and created the environment

**Problem:**

when the environment is created, it did not have the `m4.xlarge`, rather got created with default instance type as `t2.micro`. But when uploaded the zipped version of this folder contents into the environment from console ( excluding the .elasticbeanstalk folder ), `ebextensions` folder configuration is picked up. Its only with the `option_settings` not getting worked, but the other resources like `files`, `commands` are getting reflected both from command line and from the file upload.

I feel its kind of very small thing missing which I am not able to figure it out from blogs and documentation. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During `eb create`, the EBCLI passes it's own defaults for many of the option settings, among which is the instance type. Since, the EBCLI does not parse .ebextensions, and the Beanstalk service prefers the defaults passed by the EBCLI, the instance type specified in your .ebextensions are disregarded.

There are two ways to get around this:

1. call `eb config` after `eb create`. In the interactive mode, change the instance type, and save and exit.
2. call `eb create` as `eb create -i m4.xlarge`

Comment: Yes we could pass the options from command line. But I suppose there should be some significance of `option_settings` where all the options which are provided as command line could be mentioned.

Comment: After going through the docs in detail I have found https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-precedence where the precedence order is defined and the defaults always override the explicit only in the case of recommended values. @progfan, let know if this understanding is correct.

Comment: @KartikNarayanaMaringanti, your understanding is correct.